# POST a request with NO JSON inside a JSON in SpringBoot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-boot with JPA. I want to get rid of the redundant JSON. What is the correct approach?

HAVE *(default)*:

```
{
    "latitude":20.0,
    "longitude":20.0,
    "picturesURLs": [
        "google.com",
        "unaimagen.com"
        ],
    "animal":{
        "id": 1
    },
    "usuario": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "longitudAnimal": "123.345"
}
```

WANT:

```
{
    "latitude":20.0,
    "longitude":20.0,
    "picturesURLs": [
        "google.com",
        "unaimagen.com"
        ],
    "animal": 1,
    "usuario": 1,
    "longitudAnimal": "123.345"
}
```

Comment: create a new class in `WANT` format

Comment: this may helps you.. https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a DTO (Data Transfer Object). [Check this link](https://stackabuse.com/data-transfer-object-pattern-in-java-implementation-and-mapping/)